# Watermark full width and height using GD library

Tags: php, gd

Alright so I am trying to set this watermark to full width and height so it fills the image but for some reason it keeps popping up in its original size only.

So basically instead of stretching the watermark to fit the image, not it just places the watermark in the middle of the image...

```
    function watermark($sourcefile, $watermarkfile) {

    #
    # $sourcefile = Filename of the picture to be watermarked.
    # $watermarkfile = Filename of the 24-bit PNG watermark file.
    #

    //Get the resource ids of the pictures
    $watermarkfile_id = imagecreatefrompng($watermarkfile);

    imageAlphaBlending($watermarkfile_id, false);
    imageSaveAlpha($watermarkfile_id, true);

    $fileType = strtolower(substr($sourcefile, strlen($sourcefile)-3));

    switch($fileType) {
        case('gif'):
            $sourcefile_id = imagecreatefromgif($sourcefile);
            break;

        case('png'):
            $sourcefile_id = imagecreatefrompng($sourcefile);
            break;

        default:
            $sourcefile_id = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourcefile);
    }

    //Get the sizes of both pix   
  $sourcefile_width=imageSX($sourcefile_id);
  $sourcefile_height=imageSY($sourcefile_id);
  $watermarkfile_width=imageSX($watermarkfile_id);
  $watermarkfile_height=imageSY($watermarkfile_id);

    $dest_x = ( $sourcefile_width / 2 ) - ( $watermarkfile_width / 2 );
    $dest_y = ( $sourcefile_height / 2 ) - ( $watermarkfile_height / 2 );

    // if a gif, we have to upsample it to a truecolor image
    if($fileType == 'gif') {
        // create an empty truecolor container
        $tempimage = imagecreatetruecolor($sourcefile_width,
                                                                            $sourcefile_height);

        // copy the 8-bit gif into the truecolor image
        imagecopy($tempimage, $sourcefile_id, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                            $sourcefile_width, $sourcefile_height);

        // copy the source_id int
        $sourcefile_id = $tempimage;
    }

    imagecopy($sourcefile_id, $watermarkfile_id, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0,
                        $watermarkfile_width, $watermarkfile_height);

    //Create a jpeg out of the modified picture
    switch($fileType) {

        // remember we don't need gif any more, so we use only png or jpeg.
        // See the upsaple code immediately above to see how we handle gifs
        case('png'):
            header("Content-type: image/png");
            imagepng ($sourcefile_id);
            break;

        default:
            header("Content-type: image/jpg");
            imagejpeg ($sourcefile_id);
    }           

    imagedestroy($sourcefile_id);
    imagedestroy($watermarkfile_id);

}
```

Comment: But your code just puts it into the middle of the newly image. You not even tried to do something different? You even calculating with `$dest_x` and `$dest_y` the middle... I do not get your question, maybe first try do stretch the image? And use as coordinates `0,0` and `$sourcefile_width`,`$sourcefile_height` as width/height)

Comment: I am trying to "stretch" the watermark over the entire source image

Answer (score 0):

Use `imagescale` to sclae your watermark image to the same size as your source image and then use `imagecopy`:

```
$scaled_id = imagescale($watermarkfile_id, $sourcefile_width, $sourcefile_height);
imagecopy($sourcefile_id, $scaled_id, 0, 0, 0, 0, $watermarkfile_width, $watermarkfile_height);
```